# Is it possible to use openstack from a remote computer to configure juju in my machine?

Tags: juju, openstack

If my task is to work around juju what is the prerequisites? from where I have to begin particularly if I'm using virtual box or remotely connecting to a computer which has virtual box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juju doesn't really care where it is installed as long as it has access and credentials to the cloud you specify. This can be on your laptop/desktop or a shared instance in a VM.

Comment: thanks jorge, kindly help me to get started , i mean where i have to start looking if im completely new,plz give the list of topics (if i have to learn juju,openstack,MAAS)on the order of precedence to go through..and if possible plz share the links too.

Comment: Please ask a new question outlining what you're trying to do, depending on what your goal is the order of tools you want/need to use can be important.